# Disable RIght click in Adobe FLash Player 10

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, flash

Our application uses Internet Explorer ActiveX control to show the help content. If the content has video, it is played through Adobe Flash Player. If the user does right click on the video played, popup menu is showed.

I tried restricting WM_RBUTTONDOWN, WM_MOUSEACTIVATE, WM_PARENTNOTIFY events, but still in Spy++, I could see a post message WM_RBUTTONDOWN event.

We don't have the control to the video file played. Is there any way to disable the right click on Adobe Flash Player, when it is installed .?